# Delete button using SQL not working properly

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am working on a discography project and I'm having an issue where the Delete Selection button isn't deleting the row. So far my connection to the DB is working, it echos the information properly but actually deleting the row from the DB isn't happening. I am currently using MySQLi.

Here is the full code right here:

```
<?php
include '../includes/connection.php';
//Include from admin folder
include './includes/login.php';
login();

// initialize flags
$OK = false;
$deleted = false;
$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();

if (isset($_GET['id']) && !$_POST) {
    // prepare SQL query
    $sql = 'SELECT id, album_name FROM album2img WHERE id = ?';
    if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) {
        // bind the query parameters
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['id']);
        // execute the query, and fetch the result
        $OK = $stmt->execute();
        // bind the result to variables
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $album_name);
        $stmt->fetch();
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM album2img WHERE id = ?';
    if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) {
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['id']);
        $stmt->execute();
        // if there's an error affected_rows is -1
        if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
            $deleted = true;
        } else {
            $error = 'There was a problem deleting the record.';
        }
    }
}

if ($deleted || isset($_POST['cancel']) || !isset($_GET['id']))  {
    header('Location: http://localhost/3rdquarterproject/admin/album_list.php');
    exit;
}

// if any SQL query fails, get the error message
if (isset($stmt) && !$OK && !$deleted) {
    $error .= $stmt->error;
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Delete Album</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Delete Album</h1>
    <?php
    if (isset($error) && !empty($error)) {
        echo "<p>Error: $error</p>";
    }
    if($id == 0) { ?>
        <p>Invalid request: record does not exist.</p>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <p>Please confirm that you want to delete the following item. This action cannot be undone.</p>
        <p><?php echo $id; echo ". "; echo $album_name; ?></p>
    <?php } ?>
    <form method="post" action="album_delete.php">
        <p>
            <?php if(isset($id) && $id > 0) { ?>
                <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Confirm Deletion">
            <?php } ?>
            <input name="cancel" type="submit" value="Cancel">
            <?php if(isset($id) && $id > 0) { ?>
                <input name="album_name" type="hidden" value="<?= $album_name; ?>">
            <?php } ?>
        </p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure if I'm using the prepared statements properly on the delete section:

```
    if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM album2img WHERE id = ?';
    if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) {
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['id']);
        $stmt->execute();
        // if there's an error affected_rows is -1
        if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
            $deleted = true;
        } else {
            $error = 'There was a problem deleting the record.';
        }
    }
}
```

I'm still pretty new at this so look forward to everyone's responses!

Comment: Where is `$_POST['id']` coming from?

Comment: A tip: people reading your question have no access to your PC. As a consequence, they have *absolutely no idea*  what does " isn't happening" mean. You are their only source of information and therefore have to be a bit more descriptive about what is happening and what you actually see

Comment: Which information does it show? *isn't happening* isn't a good description of your problem. Make some effort to debug your code line-by-line and/or show us some more details. Also as already asked are you sure that your `$_POST['id']` pass valid data? I cannot see any field with `name="id"` in your form did you mean `$_POST['album_name']` or `<input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?= $id; ?>">`?.

Comment: To get errors out of PHP even in a LIVE environment add these 4 lines to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: @RiggsFolly i believe that in a LIVE environment display_errors must be 0, not 1

Comment: @YourCommonSense The point of that comment was that even if you are developing on a PHP configured into a LIVE mode, this will override it and  still produce errors on the screen, I should probably add back the phrase "Only while testing or debugging"